# result as numbers and multiple params in the same time - ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using `PDO` with mySQL.
Have problem with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` - I'd have to have `true` and `false` in the same time.

If `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to `true` PDO return number values as strings ('column'=>'1' instead of 'column'=>1).

When I set `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false` I cannot use the same param multiple times (I've got error with query ex: `"select id, (select 1 from outtable o WHERE o.id=table.id and o.value=:value) FROM table WHERE (select 1 from outtable o WHERE o.id=table.id and o.value=:value)=1"` - params `$params['value']=1`

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: Also, maybe you're overcomplicating things - your example seems equivalent to me to `SELECT table.id FROM table JOIN outtable USING (id) WHERE outtable.value = :value`, and maybe your real query might be likewise streamlined?

Comment: It's just example of showing multiple params sql. In fact I'm generating all sql on arrays. It' complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for that.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, **unless emulation mode is on**.

You can add a unique marker to each parameter occurrence, and bind the parameter value multiple times:

Before:

... :value, ... :value, ... :value

After:

... :value, ... :value02, ... :value03

You can use `preg_replace` with a lambda function to do this. Say you have a function

```
function runSQL($query, $params) {

}
```

where e.g. `$params = [ 'value' => [ 42, PDO::INT ] ]`

you can run a `preg_replace` with an incremental counter starting from 0, if counter is 0 you do not replace, otherwise you append the counter (maybe prefixed) to the variable name and you add, say, `[ ":{$key}_02", $params[$i][0], $params[$i][1] ]` to `$params`. After that, you `bindParam` `$params` in a `foreach` cycle.